# How to get date of a day in a week in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to get Date of a specific day based on its sequence in a week like

```
 GetDate(22, 4);
```

which needs to return the date of 4th day in 22nd weeks of current year. How can I do this?

```
void Main()
{
    int months;
    var year = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy");
    months = GetWeeksInYear( Convert.ToInt32(year));
    Console.WriteLine(months);
}

public int GetWeeksInYear(int year)
{
      DateTimeFormatInfo dfi = DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;
      DateTime date1 = new DateTime(year, 12, 31);
      Calendar cal = dfi.Calendar;
      return  cal.GetWeekOfYear(date1, dfi.CalendarWeekRule, dfi.FirstDayOfWeek);    
}

public int GetDate(int weekNo, int dayNo)
{
  return // Date
}
```

Comment: You probably want `public DateTime GetDate`, not `int` as return type.

Comment: You need the year at least due to leap years. I would probably find what value `GetDate(1,1)` should return then add `21 * 7 + 3` days to it.

Comment: Are you treating "weeks" as a full week (Sunday through Saturday or cultural variation) or as a set of 7 days? i.e. Should `GetDate(1, 1);` return  the first Sunday (or whatever) of the year, or should it always return January 1st?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add the number of days from the beginning of the year:

```
var dt = new DateTime(year, 1, 1);
dt = dt.AddDays(weekNo * 7 + dayNo);
var date = dt.Date;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple way would be to take Jan 1 of year and add number of days,

```
DateTime day = new DateTime(year, 1, 1).AddDays((week * 7) + days);
```

Answer (score 0):

firstable the week of the year is a calendar calculation and locale dependent value so you have to consider that when giving the week number...
So you are for sure missing the use of something like

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar;
```